# Char* input check if it is hex or dec and parse it into unsigned short using appropriate error handling and reporting

Tags: c++

I am trying to parse the input into unsigned short. The input can be anything but we can only accept hex or decimal. It needs to fit into unsigned short therefore no negative values or over 0xffff (65535). Invalid values must report errors appropriately and with enough information using C++ features.

My attempt (but it doesn't check for invalid hex values e.g. 5xffff):

```
void parse_input(char *input, unsigned short &output)
{
    std::string soutput(input);

    int myint1;

    try
    {
        myint1 = std::stoi(soutput, 0, 0);
        if (myint1 > std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max())
        {
            std::cerr << "Value: " << myint1
                      << " is out of bounds!" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        output = myint1;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Another attempt which also doesn't do all that (and apparently usage of errno is not acceptable):

```
auto n = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);
if (errno == ERANGE || n > std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max()) {

}
else {

}
```

So the actual question based on the above is, what is the most efficient and effective way to resolve this using C++ features? Please provide an example.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ron Without going into the details of the whole program, I am trying to parse user input and parse it into an unsigned short frame buffer for RGBs.

For example valid inputs:
some.exe 0x0 0x2
some.exe 65 255
some.exe 200 0 30
some.exe 0 0 3200 1800
etc
are valid inputs anything else is not.

Comment: If you want to check if digit is hexadecimal then there are some C-ish functions such as: [std::isxdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isxdigit) or [std::isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) for decimal numbers.

Comment: @user3270371 It looks you'll only need to check for presence of a `0x` prefix. I'd write a special I/O manipulator for that.

Comment: What does - "Invalid values must report errors appropriately and with enough information" mean?  Why isn't `stringstream >> unsigned_short` good enough?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I am not familiar with stringstream so I will have a read about it now. In regards to the first part of your question, it means for example if the value is bigger than 65535, it must report "out of bound" kind of message, if it is invalid input for example 5xhhhh must report something as well appropriately. Basically, a way to handle and report most of these invalid cases. Hopefully, that answers your question.

I suspect, I can do that with try catch but is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Normal methods won't differentiate between these cases, so you'd have to write your own int parser.  In particular "5xff" is a valid decimal int 5.

Comment: It feels that the solution appears to be something along the lines of using std::isdigit first and if that's invalid then check for the first two characters to match for "0x" and if that's true then use std::isxdigit and then parse the information to unsigned short based on the code above.

I cannot help but feel there must be a better solution than that.

Answer (score 1):

> So the actual question based on the above is, what is the most efficient and effective way to resolve this using C++ features? Please provide an example.

As your input numbers seem to be distinguished using a `0x` for hex input and no prefix for decimal numbers, here's a small solution using a custom I/O manipulator:

```
std::istream& hex_or_decimal(std::istream& is) {

    char peek = is.peek();
    int zero_count = 0;
    while(peek == '0' || std::isspace(peek)) {
        if(peek == '0') {
            ++zero_count;
        }

        // Consume 0 prefixes as they wont affect the result
        char dummy;
        is.get(dummy);
        peek = is.peek();
        if((peek == 'x' || zero_count) && zero_count <= 1) {
            is.get(dummy);
            is >> std::hex;
            return is;
        }
    }

    is >> std::dec;
    return is;
}
```

And use that like:

```
int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss { "5 0x42 33 044 00x777 0x55" };

    short input = 0;
    while(iss >> hex_or_decimal >> input) {
        std::cout << std::dec << input 
                  << " 0x" << std::hex << input << std::endl;
    }
    if(iss.fail()) {
       std::cerr << "Invalid input!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
5 0x5
66 0x42
33 0x21
44 0x2c
Invalid input!
```

See the live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c285b5e3f336c295) please.

---

<sub>**Note:**

The `5xfffff` value is signalled as invalid after `5` was consumed correctly by the stream (see the demonstration [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/930351ef71a58ff4))</sub>

---

You can easily adapt that to your needs (e.g. throwing an exception at invalid input) using the `std::istream` standard capabilities and flags.

E.g.:

**Thowing and catching exceptions**

```
int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss { "5 0x42 33 044 00x777 0x55" };
    iss.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit); // <<<

    try {
        short input = 0;
        while(iss >> hex_or_decimal >> input) {
            std::cout << std::dec << input 
                      << " 0x" << std::hex << input << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::ios_base::failure &fail) { <<<
        std::cerr << "Invalid input!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't think `00xa` or `0 xa` should be valid.

Comment: @aschepler Well, true. But I tried to point out for the most efficient way. It's pretty easy to add more parsing states here.

Comment: @aschepler Okeh! Fixed that.